# Como criar relacionamentos usando a Indexed Database API do HTML 5?

Tags: javascript, html5, indexeddb

Alguém sabe me dizer qual a melhor forma de relacionar dados usando os Indexed Databases do HTML 5? Já vi muitos exemplos do funcionamento da API, mas em nenhum deles vi dados sendo relacionados. Por exemplo, como ficariam relacionamentos 1:N... 1:1... N:N...

Comment: Não é possível, mas você pode armazenar um objeto como valor do campo, apesar disto não garantir a integridade, pelo menos irá permitir que navegue entre as entidades.

Comment: o que o @TobyMosque diz é certo, a DB de HTML5 é mais uma nosql que uma SQL

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo usar a lib do Google para IndexedDB [lovefield](https://github.com/google/lovefield).

Exemplo de uso:

```
# pseudo código da query
SELECT * FROM photo
  INNER JOIN album
    ON photo.albumId = album.id
  WHERE album.id = '1'
```

```js
// Usando o lovefield para executar a query com innerJoin
var schemaBuilder = lf.schema.create('albums', 1);

schemaBuilder.createTable('Album')
  .addColumn('id', lf.Type.INTEGER)
  .addColumn('title', lf.Type.STRING);

schemaBuilder.createTable('Photo')
  .addColumn('photoId', lf.Type.INTEGER)
  .addColumn('title', lf.Type.STRING)
  .addColumn('albumId', lf.Type.INTEGER);

schemaBuilder.connect().then(function(db) {
  var schema = db.getSchema();
  var p = schema.table('Photo');
  var a = schema.table('Album');

  db.select()
    .from(p)
    .innerJoin(a, p.albumId.eq(a.id))
    .where(a.id.eq(1))
    .exec();
});
```